# How to open and operate in different browser tabs(Selenium,Python)?

Tags: python, selenium

Like I have to open different tabs of same url lets say [www.seleniumhq.com](http://www.seleniumhq.com) and then operate differently in each tab.... Pls help!!!

I just want to open same url in different tabs and be able to switch to different tabs in browser –

Comment: I just want to open same url in different tabs and be able to switch to different tabs in browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example if you want to open the same url in 3 new tabs (4 tabs in total), you can try something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.selenium.dev/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(url)

for x in range(3):
    driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[len(driver.window_handles)-1])
    driver.get(url)
```